# Get few characters from string without white space

Tags: php, string

Don't judge my question by it's title. I can do this by two or three PHP string functions.But i want to know is it possible with one simple function.

Here is my question :

I've string like `Stack OverFlow`. Now i want only 7 characters from it but without space. So my output would be `StackOv`. When i used `substr` it gives me `Stack O` by obvious reason.

I know i can use `str_replace` or `preg_replace` to remove space and then use `substr`. But i want to know if there is other way.

Comment: Any reason why you want to avoid using those two functions?

Comment: Just kidding. I seriously want to know simple and clear method with one function.

Comment: Well, it's not something that is used very common, and it can be easily replaced by those two functions, so I highly doubt there is some method that combines them. Unless you make one yourself of course. :)

Comment: This is the most silly question and comments I've read all day :)

Comment: Wrap the two other function calls in a new function ~ that's kind of the same as having only one function, tada

Comment: @Michael I can understand. Some people often use `silly question` when they don't have answer.

Comment: Of course that's silly question. Do you think the function which you are looking for would have some magic implementation that it does not call any in-built function like `substr` or `str_replace`?

Comment: OK thanks @dikesh for your kind information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Stack OverFlow';
$arrString = str_split($string);
$stringResult = '';
$length = 7;
for ($i=0; $i<$length;$i++)
{
    if($arrString[$i] != ' ')
    {
       $stringResult+= $arrString[$i];
    }else{ 
       $i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `substr(str_replace(" ", "", $str), 0, $len);` ? But that's not what is asked.

Comment: I have said the same.

Comment: Well I retract, it's not "optimal", it's easy to write, otherwise in n>1.000.000  executions  or $string length > 1.000.000 my answer will perform better, "str_replace" need to look at every character in string, for-function works until reach length

Comment: This results in an infinite loop when your `else` statement gets hit.

Comment: Try removing your else statement and modifying your for loop to check that `$i` is less than `$arrString` length and `$stringResult` length is less than `$length`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which does the same as `str_replace` and `substr`.

```
function getCharacters($string, $length) {
return substr(str_replace(' ', '', $string), 0, $length)
}
```

I don't think there is another way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

> I seriously want to know simple and clear method with **one** function

What is the reason for this? What is the matter with two functions?

## Answering your question

To just remove the **spaces**, use `str_replace`:

```
$string = 'Stack OverFlow';
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For **all whitespace**, use `preg_replace`:

```
$string = 'Stack OverFlow';
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Then you will use `substr`:

```
$result = substr( $string, 0 , 7 );
```